# software prefetch generating cache miss

Tags: c, caching, x86-64, perf

I am trying to do some performance improvement with software prefetching on a large array, ~50 million entries, obviously not fitting in L3 cache. Access to array is random, but I have some predictability on which location I am going to access next. Interestingly prefetch instruction is causing cache miss, before actual access.

```
const struct _bucket *prim_bkt;
prim_bkt  = &(h->buckets[prim_bucket_idx]);
__builtin_prefetch(prim_bkt,0, 3);
```

After lot of instruction actual dereferencing of prim_bkt variable

To verify cache miss I actually commented dereferencing of variable `prim_bkt`, still same amount of cache miss I am seeing. If I remove the prefetch part I have zero LLC cache miss. So real question is does a prefetch cause cache miss/Am I doing something silly in the above code.
I am using intel haswell x86-64 bit arch on cent os 7. Any cache expert here to help.

Things I already know:
Need enough gap between prefetch and actual access. That is well taken care of.

Tried with T0, T1, T3 and non temporal prefetch instructions, and all are causing LLC cache miss.
Perf tool is used for cache measurement.

**Edit**:
I start measuring LLC miss using ocperf.py. This is the command I used.

`./ocperf.py stat -e offcore_response.demand_data_rd.llc_miss.local_dram -C 16 sleep 10`.
I am interested only in core 16, which run this piece of code. I see similar behavior like perf output. I am not deferencing actual pointer, So in theory it should be zero llc miss. Just doing prefetch and ocperf counter is 34 million(`34,552,049- offcore_response_demand_data_rd_llc_miss_local_dram`). If I remove prefetch line llc miss is ~zero.

*Definition of this counter as per ocperf.py help:
offcore_response.demand_data_rd.llc_miss.local_dram - Counts demand data reads miss the L3 and the data is returned from local dram*

Comment: You're just asking whether it's normal for the perf counters to count software-prefetches as cache misses when they miss?  That doesn't sound normal if you're looking at misses for loads.  Which actual `perf` event did you use?  Also, does your version of `perf` on CentOS7 have the same event name->code bug that [John McAlpin is talking about in this thread?](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/557604).  That might explain it.  Maybe also try `ocperf.py` (see the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: perf version 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64.debug.  This is the perf command executed: `perf stat -e cache-references:u,cache-misses:u,L1-dcache-load-misses:u,L1-dcache-loads:u,L1-dcache-prefetch-misses:u,L1-dcache-store-misses:u,L1-dcache-stores:u,dTLB-load-misses:u,dTLB-loads:u,dTLB-store-misses:u,dTLB-stores:u,LLC-load-misses:u,LLC-loads:u,LLC-prefetch-misses:u,LLC-prefetches:u,LLC-store-misses:u -C 16 sleep 10`

Comment: Any idea which event to be used in ocperf.py to monitor actual cache miss without including prefetch miss. I read through help and confused about which event to be used

Comment: IDK, I don't have a SnB-family CPU to test on ATM.  Intel's manuals should document what each events is supposed to mean, but they'll use different names than `perf` does.  Esp. for `perf`'s generic names like `LLC-loads`.  Intel's name for the event counter that perf actually uses for that even will be something involving uops.

Comment: `void rte_prefetch0(const volatile void *p){
        asm volatile ("prefetcht0 %[p]" : : [p] "m" (*(const volatile char *)p));
}`                                                                                                          This is one of the prefetch example I have seen. I am not good at assembly, but looking at `*(const volatile char *)p`, Is this code trying to deference `p` in this function itself?. Is that the cause of cache miss in my code?

Comment: That looks normal and fine.  The `"m"` constraint means the inline asm sees the address, not the value, so it's like `&*p`.

Comment: `./ocperf.py stat -e offcore_response.demand_data_rd.llc_miss.local_dram -C 16 sleep 10`. This command also giving similar results as perf. I have only prefetch in code and no actual access of data. But still  `offcore_response.demand_data_rd.llc_miss.local_dram` is 34 million. If I just remove prefetcht0 line alone, this counter is close to zero. I guess `demand_data_rd` will not include prefetch misses.

Comment: Why are you profiling system-wide activity on CPU#16?  Why not just profile your test program with `perf stat ./my_microbenchmark`?  So did you find a counter that counts only load misses, not prefetch misses?  Or is there still a mystery?  Please edit the question to update it.  Future readers that might be able to help you should just be able to look at the question and see what you're actually asking, without reading the comment thread.

Comment: My Application is highly thread aware and performance issue is on thread-16 which run on core 16. WIll update original question with more details. Thanks

Comment: Is this a multi-socket system and your program is running (pinned) on one socket and is trying to access memory attached to a different socket? Also, are you able to diagnose the symptoms in terms of effects on actual execution speed? Sometimes the counters have architectural generation specific meanings which don't match our intuitive understanding of cache systems.